# Unable to use two XMLHTTP.OPEN at the same time

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am quite new in using Ajax requests using Php. Currently i am having two Php pages called getdata.php and getdata1.php with 2 Div tags called txtHint and uniHint.

I want both the div tag should display the results from both the php pages. Unfortunately, I am not sure about the usage of two XMLHTTP request at the same, Kindly help.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementById("uniHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
};

xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q1="+topping,true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata1.php?q1="+topping,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```